# I'm having trouble with a mongodb function that should be finding duplicates

Tags: mongodb

I have the following function that is supposed to be returning the _id value of duplicates based on the email key.  However, no matter what I've tried, I can't get the function to return anything other than any empty object.  What am I missing here? Or is there a better approach I should be considering?

```
var duplicates = [];
db.medicallists
  .aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          email: "$email"
        },
        duplicate_ids: { $addToSet: "$_id" },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        count: { $gt: 1 }
      }
    },
    
  ], { allowDiskUse: true })
  .forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.duplicate_ids.shift(); // First element skipped for deleting
    doc.duplicate_ids.forEach(function(dupId) {
      duplicates.push(dupId); // Getting all duplicate ids
    });
  });
printjson(duplicates);
```

EDIT:
Here is a sample document:

```
{
_id : 5a2fed0c8023cf7ea2346067,
primary_spec : "Addiction Medicine",
first_name : "John",
last_name : "Sample",
city : "Las Vegas",
state : "NV",
phone : "1111111111",
fax : "1111111111",
email : "sample@aol.com"
}
```

Comment: Could you show a sample document?

Comment: @codemonkey Good idea.  I had edited the question to include that.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your specific query on a similar data set and it works fine. `printjson(duplicates);` prints out all the duplicate ids.

Also this will, in fact, remove all the duplicate entries based on email:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        email: "$email"
      },
      duplicate_ids: {
        $push: "$_id"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: {
        $gt: 1
      }
    }
  },
  
]).forEach(function(doc){
  doc.duplicate_ids.shift();
  db.collection.remove({
    _id: {
      $in: doc.duplicate_ids
    }
  });
})
```

My starting set was:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6014331de1ef9ab1f708ddd9"),
        "item" : "card",
        "email" : "zzz@yahoo.com"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6014331de1ef9ab1f708ddda"),
        "item" : "card",
        "email" : "eee@yahoo.com"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6014331de1ef9ab1f708dddb"),
        "item" : "card",
        "email" : "zzz@yahoo.com"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6014331de1ef9ab1f708dddc"),
        "item" : "card",
        "email" : "aaa@yahoo.com"
}
```

After running the query, it turned to:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6014331de1ef9ab1f708ddd9"),
        "item" : "card",
        "email" : "zzz@yahoo.com"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6014331de1ef9ab1f708ddda"),
        "item" : "card",
        "email" : "eee@yahoo.com"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6014331de1ef9ab1f708dddc"),
        "item" : "card",
        "email" : "aaa@yahoo.com"
}
```

Tested on MongoDB server version: 4.2.7

Comment: Thank you!  I modified my script so that it matched what you did.  It returns True, but then none of the duplicate records are removed from the collection.  Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @ffcgoering Run just the aggregation part and see if you are actaully returning any records. I assume you're in the terminal so run the part from `db.medicallists.aggregate([...` to `], { allowDiskUse: true })` and see what you get.

Comment: Running just the aggregation part just returns "true"

Comment: @ffcgoering So that seems to be the issue. The aggregation does not seem to grab anything. Try changing the part `$gt: 1` to `$gt: 0` in your aggregation and see if you get anything. If you do, then there is just no duplicate emails. If you still don't, they something else is going on. Here is a playground for you to test things: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZPJQkL8zr_h